# How to release memory of elastic search service?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm now using Elastic Search service version 2.3.3 on Windows 7.
The memory usage of the service increase by each query statement but not release although the application was exit.
I tried to clear cached data as below command but the memory was still kept.

```
POST /_cache/clear
```

Is there anyway to release it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like you are having trouble with GC. post your logs for elastic and also  check if cluster is swapping memory from disk, try pasting logs for disk memory swapping as well.

Comment: also post your mappings, query and cluster configurations